# Css auto height issue with alignment

Tags: css

```
 #container
 {
   background: #787234;
   width:980px;
   height:auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   position:relative;
   //float:left;
}
```

`container` height is set to auto. Still I am facing height issue.  Since the DIV is aligned to center I am not able to use `float:left`.

Please tell me how to get the `height:auto` without using `float:left`

[here is the code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhy3q/)

**Edit:**

`float:left` is giving me the result but my `div` won't be in center if I use `float:left`.

**Solved: (Not having 100 Reputation to Answer this )**

Since the `#container` is aligned to center, it's giving me `height:auto` issue. I solved by creating a sub-container `div` having `float:left`

Hence, `float:left` is the answer which I cannot use in `#container`.

```
#container
{
  width:980px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#sub-container
{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  float:left;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: `height: auto` is working - it's the default.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `height:auto` will set the height of the element to that of its contents (in this case, 0px).

Comment: I have contents inside #container, still I am facing this issue

Comment: What exactly is your expectation ? What will you have in your div ? Text and you need to wrap so that height increases ? You didn't tell your problem

Comment: Show us more code then and what exactly is breaking

Comment: There is no element that contains #container, therefore there is no height for #container being that `height:auto` would set #container to the height of what div it is contained in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not seem to understand what your CSS is doing. You are aligning the div to the center using `margin-left` and `margin-right`, then you also want to `float` it to the left. These two styles are in conflict and will not work. Either you want the div in the middle, or on the left, it can't be both at the same time.

Also, the `height` is set to `auto` by default so you shouldn't have to explicitly state this.

Comment: I mentioned, float:left gives me background of the #container as default. but when I remove it #container won't shows background #FFF, i.e height faces some issue here

Comment: no you did not mention... and I have no idea what that means. please provide more code in your example to illustrate the issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks, My issue solved. I created a new div having float:left inside #container

Comment: Since the #container is aligned to center, its giving me height:auto issue. I solved by creating a sub-container div having float:left

Hence, float:left is the answer which I cannot use in #container

    #container
    {
    width:980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
 
    #sub-container
    {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    background: #FFF;
    }

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem and I found a solution:

```
div#container {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I got many div's in the container, but it won't work without `overflow:hidden;`.

When I put it in the above code, it works very well.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. The div I was working with had a calculated height that was the size of the window (768px). I had `height:auto;` set and the combined height of the child elements was 80px.

The reason why was because I had this in my css

```
div.my-div {
  top:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  height:auto;
  position:fixed;
}
```

The `top:0px;` and the `bottom:0px;` caused the calculated height to be the size of the window. I removed the `bottom:0px;` and everything was right again.